# Why coinbase doesn't address callback?

Tags: client, blockchain.info, coinbase.com, payment-processors

I am using PHP cURL to generate new address from coinbase. As per this [documentation](https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/callbacks) we get notification on the callback url when any transaction is made on the generated address. But I am not getting any callback from coinbase when I receive any payment.

I want to achieve the following:

1. Generate a bitcoin address
2. Store the the generated address & the amount with it's user who paid it.

I am facing the problem in getting callback. I get payment in the coinbase & email saying that you received this amount etc., but no callbacks.

Also please suggest me that whether the coinbase is secure or not.
If not, what should I go for? I want to get the above things done.

Answer (score -2):

Give your website address in Merchant Settings then check by clicking Test